# How to hide/disable console output from Talkey text to speech?

Tags: python, console, output, text-to-speech

I have this code:

```
import talkey
tts = talkey.Talkey()
tts.say("hello world", 'en')
```

It outputs this to the console and plays sound when I run it:

```
Playing WAVE '/tmp/tmplGOau7.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 22050 Hz, Mono
```

I don't want any text-output from the Talkey, is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

The question is, do you want the console at all. Because if not, try to use the run the script via

```
pythonw.exe
```

instead of

```
python.exe
```

Comment: I want console output, but not within the Talkey package.

Comment: Talkey has some docs but it's pretty sparce and I can't find option for disabling it. http://talkey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Open `base.py` from talkey's folder (in my case, python3 on linux mint: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/talkey).

Near the end find this line:

`cmd = ['aplay',str(filename)]`

and change it to

`cmd = ['aplay','--quiet',str(filename)]`